# Get animation object location value when drag other object in Google Web designer

Tags: google-web-designer

I want to get animation object.location in gwd when drag other object .
Animation Object is moving y axis and drag item is waiting to get that animation object x axis.
What should I do ?

Dragstart code event

**gwd.dragger = this;
event = (event.changedTouches ? event.changedTouches[0] : event);
gwd.s = window.getComputedStyle ? getComputedStyle(this, null) : this.currentStyle;
gwd.dX = event.pageX - parseInt(gwd.s["left"]);
gwd.dY = event.pageY - parseInt(gwd.s["top"]);**

Dragmove drag event

**if (gwd.dragger) {
event = (event.changedTouches ? event.changedTouches[0] : event);
gwd.actions.events.setInlineStyle(gwd.dragger.id, "left:" + (event.pageX - gwd.dX) + "px; top:" + (event.pageY - gwd.dY) + "px");**
}

Dragstop event

**gwd.dragger = null;**

I want to get animated item left and top values pixel when drag

You can see this my ads.

https://doc-14-10-adspreview.googleusercontent.com/preview/9o5bees06oeguhr10neq55qcti27eh7n/2ma5s2dmjnvulveo4uos4qfu7ifos8ps/1664409600000/90358308/previewuser/gwd.90358308?render=blank&creativeId=gwd.90358308&irsk=CICAgODErP3t8gE&ecId=AOgHqNpAgFX7nq3p6KSPl2n47gS0-gxu3Aa9jhkOsuFMEnrCJDOlIJQMG7XhxKQuzLKQN98dGl9n

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: My problem is I need to catch bottles using drag . It is look like game but  how do I do?  I got drag object left and top location value but I cannot get bottles object left and top location values when they are playing animation. I need to get their location when dragging item event.